# Resource impact to give many HTML elements an id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I'm writing an HTML + JavaScript application that has quite strict resource limitations: it will run in the browser for ages (can be many days or more; think of kiosk mode) and should also run without any change on mobile devices. It is also only one HTML page, i.e. DOM, that uses scrolling etc. to show different content.
=> I really have to make sure not to waste any ressources (CPU, RAM)

Now I'm creating hooks that an "external" editor for such an application / page could use, to have a WYSIWYG preview when modifying the content. Here I need to address elements on the page - an element is a `div` that will contain further DOM elements, but it is the smallest addressable unit for the editor. (We can probably assume 100 to 1000 of those elements in this long running page)

- Now I could find the relevant element given by a "path" by an
  algorithm at runtime (not elegant, but lookup time is ok in an
  interactive environment).
- Or I could add an HTML `id` attribute to
  the elements which contains each individual path. (This would make my program more clear and a lookup very fast)

But I don't know the resource impact of giving so many elements an `id` attribute...

How much RAM would it need? Only the strings and a couple of pointers each?
Or would it create lots of new and heavy internal structures in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having additional ID attributes on your elements would have very minimal impact on any resource use.

The main effect would be that it could increase file size ever so slightly depending on how many and how long IDs you were to use.

Comment: That's my hope :) - file size is not a problem here, as the page get's created dynamically in JavaScript out of a config file.